# PDE with constant coefficients has different solutions for a change in variables and the method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem: $$\pi U_x+U_y=0$$
$$U(x,0)-x^2$$

By solving with method of characteristics we find that: $$y'=\frac{1}{\pi} \implies y(x)=\frac{x}{\pi}+C \implies C=y-\frac{x}{\pi}$$
Because $U_x(x,y(x)) =0$ we have that: $$U(x,y)=f(C)=f(y -\frac{x}{\pi}) $$ and using our initial condition we can conclude that $U(x,y)=(y-\frac{x}{\pi})^2 $.

But here is where I have an issue, the solution given in my lecture notes uses the change of coordinates $$\bar{x}=\pi x+y $$
$$\bar{y}=x-\pi y $$
Because this PDE has constant coefficients we simply have that $U(x,y) = f(\bar{y})=f(x-\pi y)$.
But  if we use our initial condition, we find that $$U(x,y)=(x- \pi y)^2 \neq (y-\frac{x}{\pi})^2 $$
Why is it that my method is incorrect? I can see that we can multiply $(y-\frac{x}{\pi})$ by $-\pi$ to get the same form as my lecturers solution. Are solutions equivalent up to a constant multiple?

Comment: Your PDE is linear, if $U$ is a solution, then for every $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, $\alpha U$ is also a solution. Try multiplying $(y-\frac{x}{\pi})^2$ by $\pi^2$.

Comment: @Hamdiken Thank you, I suspected it might have been something along those lines.

Comment: Some comments: (1) I suppose you meant to write $U(x,0)=x^2$ rather than $U(x,0)-x^2$. (2) It's not true that $U_x(x,y(x))=0$. You should write it as $\frac{d}{dx} \bigl( U(x,y(x)) \bigr) = 0$. (Substitute $y=y(x)$ first, then differentiate. Not the other way around!) (3) Your claim “using our initial condition we can conclude that $U(x,y) = (y-\frac{x}{\pi})^2$” is obviously incorrect, since that function satisfies $U(x,0)=x^2/\pi^2$ and not $U(x,0)=x^2$. In order for us to understand where you went wrong, if would be helpful if you explained more about how you were thinking.